# cloud run authentication with user account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-sdk

As google [documented](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers#testing), developers can use `gcloud auth print-identity-token` to generate a development-only id_token to authenticate to Cloud Run. If I base64 decode the resulting id_token, I can see the `aud` claim is set to 32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com, which is the client_id of the [google cloud sdk](https://github.com/twistedpair/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py#L166):
[image]

Is this an exception to the rule outlined in [service-to-service authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#calling-from-outside-gcp), which says `target_audience` needs to be set to the url of the receiving service (e.g., https://xxxxx.run.app).Is `aud` and `target_audience` the same thing?

Lastly, is there an alternative way to authenticated with user account instead of service account, other than using googlecloudsdk (i.e. imaging `gcloud auth print-identity-token` doesn't exist)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's a real problem. I wrote 2 articles on [IAM limitation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c) and [Service Account Credentials API](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115), and I submitted 2 pull requests for the Google Auth Java library (I can share the link if you are interested).

Directly and easily, you can't. I provide workarounds in my article but not great enough to stop my discussions with Google now.

Comment: Hi guillaume, thanks for the clear answer and good to know that I'm not the only one who ran into the limitations of IAM. Also thanks for your excellent articles! I'd appreciate if you could share the links to your pull requests.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/pull/469#) the pull request to implement the same behavior as gcloud SDK and the command gcloud auth print-identity-token. And [the second ](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/pull/493) that use the Service Account Credentials API; with a [related articles here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115).

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: What is `32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com` useful for? I don't understand what it is.

Comment: It's your project clientID

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login):

> This command is useful when you are developing code that would
> normally use a service account but need to run the code in a local
> development environment where it's easier to provide user credentials.